# Encrypting calculation formula and saving it to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I need to have a calculation formula, which is changeable, saved and encrypted securely.

The calculation formula is used in a executable application and maintained from a web service. So, there are two executables: The web service and an exe which calculates the result according to the calculation formula.

I'm looking for a simple, lightweigt but absolutely secure solution for this. My questions are very basic, because this is the first time I'm implementing this kind of software.

So far I've thought about two possibilities:

1) Using RSA type encryption / decryption in the application itself

- Web service encrypts the formula and saves that to a (SQL Server) database
- The exe decrypts the formula
- Shoudl I save encryption keys to the code as a text? (The keys will be visible
  if someone decodes the application)
- Is there some other more sophisticated way to keep encryption keys hidden

2) Creating encrypted column for the calculation formula to SQL Server database.

- This seems a bit complicated, since I haven't found any code examples of using encrypted columns from an application.

3) Some another approach

UPDATE: Absolutely secure defined

The calculation formula should not be available as plain text for anyone who can access the computer. The server, where calculation is executed and data is stored, is maintained by ourselves but located at our customer.

The executable, which performs the calculation, reads input values, does the job and saves results into database.

Comment: Read this closely: **If the local executable has access to *anything*, then the user of that executable also has access**.  The only way you can keep your "calculation formula" safe is to *not* give it to the user: Make the calculations happen in the webservice, and provide results to the exe.

Comment: Define "absolutely secure". What are the threats? Check this out for an insight on cell-level encryption: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx